# crm 2011 OP: What server do plugins run on?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

We have a 2011 on prem. We use separate servers for app and db. We typically deploy synchronous, pre-validation, full trust plugins to the database. Can someone clarify which server resources will be impacted when a plugin runs? If we had a lot of plugins executing at the same time, would you expect the app server or db server to be impacted the most?

Update: I guess what I'm really asking is what happens behind the scenes if I trigger (either UI or app) a message on an entity to which there is a plugin attached. Specifically, when the plugin runs, given scenario above, what server memory space does the plugin run in? And does async/sync and message processing stage affect it? e.g. if plugin is synchronous + pre-validation vs. async and pre-operation....

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple possible scenarios:

1. Your plugin is registered as non-sandbox and synchronous. In this case your plugin code is running inline with the IIS process on the front-end web server(s).
2. Your plugin is registered as non-sandbox and asynchronous. Your plugin code is running in the CRM Asynchronous Windows service. This service runs as part of the "back-end server" so it may not be on the same machine(s) as the front-end web server.
3. Your plugin is registered as sandbox, either synchronous or asynchronous. In this case your plugin code is running in the CRM Sandbox Processing Service. This service also runs on the "back-end" servers.

In no scenario does your code run on the SQL Server, although it will still undoubtably consume resources from the SQL Server through queries and transactions from the front-end or back-end CRM server.

Comment: Thanks. Still have questions. For 1, if plugin registered pre/post op, can you explain how the crm system manages to get the plugin logic executed as part of the DB transaction? I have always assumed that the transaction itself is managed by the sql server so how does the plugin execution fit into that model?

Comment: The transaction is still open in the SQL server so if the post operation plugin throws an exception the transaction is rolled back.

Comment: @keerz - the concept of pre-stage and post-stage are with regards to the "Core Operation".  The Core operation is something that CRM executes without a developers involvement and part of it includes writing to (or reading from or a combination depending on which event runs the plugin).  The purpose of plugins is to intercept the message and either alter it or "do other stuff".  For simplicity, think of the pre-operation as grabbing the message before it reaches the database and post-operation as getting it after it reaches the database (but with the capability to roll back the db action).

Answer (score 2):

So the basic CRM deployment is made up of the following components:

- The web front end, this is where IIS and the CRM web site is installed. This is where synchronous plugins run.
- The back end, where the CRM asynchronous service is installed. This is where asynchronous plugins and workflows run.
- The SQL database.

Depending on your installation those components could all be on a one server, or spread across multiple servers, and you could have multiple copies load balanced on multiple servers.

Depending on what your plugin is doing and how it is doing it, all could be impacted. However in this case its probably going to be wherever the application server and SQL is installed.

You may find the following useful:

- [Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 server roles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699655(v=crm.5).aspx).
- [Event Execution Pipeline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg327941(v=crm.5).aspx).

Comment: thanks. the async service for us is on the app server. Does that mean both sync and async plugins would execute on the app server? Wondering how that works with plugins registered pre/post op as they are part of the DB transaction...I had read both links but am still not clear on what server memory is consumed by running plugins....

Comment: @keerz, Yes I think both plugins execute on the app server then. Not sure how the DB transaction is implemented. I guess the major point is that resources will be used on all servers, e.g. a plugin running on the app server (front end) accessing the DB, will use resources on both.

Comment: Not sure if I am reading [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699655.aspx#BKMK_InstallMeth) correctly but I'm starting to think that both async and sync plugins would be more likely to run on the db server. The async "service" is on the appserver but it now looks like all that does is put things into the async "queue" which seems to run on the db server. Also the article doesn't address non-sandboxed plugins...the plot thickens.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the DB server to be honest. Do you mean the back end server?

Comment: yes, we have 2 servers, what I call "app" and "db" which I assume MS calls "front" and "back"